# Find usages not working in Android Studio (View --> Tool windows missing multiple options) after upgrade

Tags: android-studio

After upgrading Android Studio to 4.1, Find Usages has stopped working.  When I highlight a function and try "Find Usages" I no longer see  a window showing different call stacks that led to function being called

Also, View --> Tool Windows missing a bunch of options (including  Find, Run, Debug).

I have tried "Invalidate Caches and restart" but no change.  I also triued reinstalling Android Studio, but still no improvement.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?